# Flexboxでコンテンツの幅に合わせて縦並びにしたい。

Tags: html, css

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上のようにflec containerに合わせてitemの幅が広がってしまうのですが、
これを"item"のコンテンツ幅に合わせるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

[html]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

      </head>

      <body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="item">item</p>
        <p class="item">item</p>
        <p class="item">item</p>
    </div>


      </body>


    </html>
```

[css]

```
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/*中の幅に合わせて縦並びにしたい*/
.container{
    display: flex;
    background: skyblue;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item{
    background: tomato;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.item に

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

を加えるとどうでしょうか

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！下記の手順で解決できました！

Answer (score 1):

```
align-items:center
```

で出来ました！